# MySQL table doesn't exist when it does exist

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
mysql_select_db('scanner');
$query = "SELECT * FROM scanner.proxy ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

it tells me:'scanner.proxy ' doesnt exist.. even though I do have it the table with the database. It is weird, cause my other queries work..but this one doesnt.

UPADTE:

Event when I put this:

```
$user='root';
            $user='root'
        $password='<removed_password>';
        $dbname = 'scanner';
        $host = 'localhost';
        $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($dbname, $link) or die (mysql_error());
```

it gives me this...

> Unknown database 'scanner'

But I can see the scanner database in the phpmyadmin

Even when I type in phpmyadmin the sql statement
SHOW TABLES FROM 'scanner'

it says it cant find scanner

Comment: maby you connect with the wrong host. not always this is localhost. try `mysql_select_db('scanner')or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Thats what I tried with the database

Comment: Does something like `show create table scanner.proxy` work?

Comment: When you say that your other queries work - are they queries on the same table in the same database, other tables in the same database, or in other databases? Basically - is this the only place that you're accessing scanner.proxy?

Comment: no..it says scanner.proxy doesnt exist :(, Marc.. All queries work on a different database, not this one

Comment: are those backticks or single-quotes? I get an error when I use single-quotes on tables or databases names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the user you use to connect has enough rights to query that table. Perhaps that table was created by another user.

EDIT: Perhaps you need to grant access to scanner from a remote location. Running this sholud help on that.

```
GRANT ALL ON scanner.* TO your_user@'IP_ofServer_where_PHP_runs' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

Comment: Wouldn't you get 'No SELECT permission' if the table existed but you don't have access rights to it?

Comment: Except in this case, maybe user has no permissions on **the database**.

Comment: Added something to be checked

Answer (score 2):

We solved this problem which occurred when connecting to multiple remote **MySQL** databases within the same script by adding a re-connect method before every `mysql_query` statement. The re-connect method invoked both `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` functions. We had previously tried setting the new link parameter to true in the connect statement(s) but We still got database errors and all kinds of funny behavior.

Comment: What a creepy hack. That should not be needed (although I know enough PHP to realise that it may be the only solution in some cases) :|

Answer (score 0):

You have set the $dbname = 'aws_backlinks', but you are trying to connect to a different database within your query.  Change your connection string to include this db instead or just connect to the server and set your database at the time of the query.

Comment: I did the change , it still wont recognise the database

Answer (score 0):

$db_host = 'localhost:Port';
Specify port for localhost. 
I was facing the same problem and specifying the port solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the argument that specifies the connection (result of mysql_connect()) in your mysql_select_db() call:

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = 'whatever';
$db_name = 'scanner';
$link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);
mysql_select_db($db_name, $link);
```

Comment: are you still getting the same error? I hope you understood that 'localhost', 'root' and 'whatever' are just examples

Comment: Only after I replied to your comment :P Anyway, can't it be there a case error? Like 'Scanner' instead of 'scanner'?